# Varnish Config with backend on different host 503 error

Tags: nginx, varnish

I am trying to setup a varnish cache where the varnish instance is hosted on one server and the backend is on a different server. They are both on aws lightsail instances. The issue I am having is when I try and go to the site, I get the `Error 503 Backend fetch failed`
error. Here is the varnish default.vcl:

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'SSL-OFFLOADED: https'

backend default {
    .host = "172.26.4.151";
    .port = "8080";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    "localhost";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED) {
        hash_data(req.http.SSL-OFFLOADED);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

The backend server has a private IP address of `172.26.4.151` and is listening on port `8080`.

Here is the nginx config for the backend host:

```
## Example configuration:
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    # use tcp connection
    # server  127.0.0.1:9000;
    # or socket
    server   unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
 }
# server {
#    listen 80;
#    server_name mage.dev;
#    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
#    set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;
#    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;
# }
#
## Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the
## command 'bin/magento deploy:mode:set' to switch modes instead.
##
## set $MAGE_MODE default; # or production or developer
##
## If you set MAGE_MODE in server config, you must pass the variable into the
## PHP entry point blocks, which are indicated below. You can pass
## it in using:
##
## fastcgi_param  MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
##
## In production mode, you should uncomment the 'expires' directive in the /static/ location block

# Modules can be loaded only at the very beginning of the Nginx config file, please move the line below to the main config file
# load_module /etc/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

server {

listen 8080;

server_name example.com *.example.com;

set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/example.com;
set $MAGE_DEBUG_SHOW_ARGS 0;

root $MAGE_ROOT/pub;

index index.php;
autoindex off;
charset UTF-8;
error_page 404 403 = /errors/404.php;
#add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=Edge";


# Deny access to sensitive files
location /.user.ini {
    deny all;
}


# PHP entry point for setup application
location ~* ^/setup($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;
    location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;

        fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=600";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

# PHP entry point for update application
location ~* ^/update($|/) {
    root $MAGE_ROOT;

    location ~ ^/update/index.php {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # Deny everything but index.php
    location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /pub/ {
    location ~ ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|custom_options|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
        deny all;
    }
    alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub/;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /static/ {
    # Uncomment the following line in production mode
    # expires max;

    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    location ~ ^/static/version\d*/ {
        rewrite ^/static/version\d*/(.*)$ /static/$1 last;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2|html|json|webmanifest)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
        expires +1y;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
        expires    off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
           rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
    }
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    include /etc/nginx/magento2-cors.conf;
}

location /media/ {

## The following section allows to offload image resizing from Magento instance to the Nginx.
## Catalog image URL format should be set accordingly.
## See https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/general/web.html#url-options
#   location ~* ^/media/catalog/.* {
#
#       # Replace placeholders and uncomment the line below to serve product images from public S3
#       # See examples of S3 authentication at https://github.com/anomalizer/ngx_aws_auth
#       # resolver 8.8.8.8;
#       # proxy_pass https://<bucket-name>.<region-name>.amazonaws.com;
#
#       set $width "-";
#       set $height "-";
#       if ($arg_width != '') {
#           set $width $arg_width;
#       }
#       if ($arg_height != '') {
#           set $height $arg_height;
#       }
#       image_filter resize $width $height;
#       image_filter_jpeg_quality 90;
#   }

    try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;

    location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|svgz|webp|avif|avifs|js|css|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        expires +1y;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        expires    off;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php$is_args$args;
    }
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
}

location /media/customer/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/downloadable/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/import/ {
    deny all;
}

location /media/custom_options/ {
    deny all;
}

location /errors/ {
    location ~* \.xml$ {
        deny all;
    }
}

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
     

    set $cors_origin "*";

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'POST, GET, OPTIONS' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,X-Cache-Hash' always;
      ### Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
    }

   add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $cors_origin always;


    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types
    text/plain
    text/css
    text/js
    text/xml
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/x-javascript
    application/json
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    image/svg+xml;
gzip_vary on;

# Banned locations (only reached if the earlier PHP entry point regexes don't match)
location ~* (\.php$|\.phtml$|\.htaccess$|\.git) {
    deny all;
}
```

This is a magento 2 site, not sure if that is relevant in this situation though.

I also have the varnish log as well:

```
*   << BeReq    >> 206       
-   Begin          bereq 205 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1620340272.761062 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 67.161.183.181
-   BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1802093982.1619119977; _gid=GA1.2.56339638.1620338153; form_key=djHykwYumX1hgtiw; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previou
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 67.161.183.181, 172.26.4.151
-   BereqHeader    grace: none
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 206
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1620340272.761100 0.000038 0.000038
-   Timestamp      Error: 1620340272.761104 0.000042 0.000004
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 22:31:12 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
-   BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   Length         280
-   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
-   End            

*   << Request  >> 205       
-   Begin          req 204 rxreq
-   Timestamp      Start: 1620340272.760977 0.000000 0.000000
-   Timestamp      Req: 1620340272.760977 0.000000 0.000000
-   VCL_use        boot
-   ReqStart       172.26.4.151 59894 a0
-   ReqMethod      GET
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqProtocol    HTTP/1.0
-   ReqHeader      Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
-   ReqHeader      X-Real-IP: 67.161.183.181
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 67.161.183.181
-   ReqHeader      Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   ReqHeader      Connection: close
-   ReqHeader      Cache-Control: max-age=0
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
-   ReqHeader      sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   ReqHeader      Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
-   ReqHeader      User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36
-   ReqHeader      Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Site: none
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
-   ReqHeader      Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
-   ReqHeader      Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1802093982.1619119977; _gid=GA1.2.56339638.1620338153; form_key=djHykwYumX1hgtiw; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previou
-   ReqUnset       X-Forwarded-For: 67.161.183.181
-   ReqHeader      X-Forwarded-For: 67.161.183.181, 172.26.4.151
-   VCL_call       RECV
-   ReqHeader      grace: none
-   ReqURL         /
-   ReqUnset       Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
-   ReqHeader      Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   VCL_return     hash
-   VCL_call       HASH
-   VCL_return     lookup
-   VCL_call       MISS
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   Link           bereq 206 fetch
-   Timestamp      Fetch: 1620340272.761154 0.000177 0.000177
-   RespProtocol   HTTP/1.1
-   RespStatus     503
-   RespReason     Backend fetch failed
-   RespHeader     Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 22:31:12 GMT
-   RespHeader     Server: Varnish
-   RespHeader     content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   RespHeader     Retry-After: 5
-   RespHeader     X-Varnish: 205
-   RespHeader     Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_call       DELIVER
-   RespUnset      Age: 0
-   RespHeader     Pragma: no-cache
-   RespHeader     Expires: -1
-   RespHeader     Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
-   RespUnset      Server: Varnish
-   RespUnset      X-Varnish: 205
-   RespUnset      Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.2)
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Timestamp      Process: 1620340272.761174 0.000197 0.000020
-   Filters        
-   RespHeader     Content-Length: 280
-   RespHeader     Connection: close
-   Timestamp      Resp: 1620340272.761206 0.000229 0.000032
-   ReqAcct        1300 0 1300 264 280 544
-   End            

*   << Session  >> 204       
-   Begin          sess 0 HTTP/1
-   SessOpen       172.26.4.151 59894 a0 172.26.8.97 6081 1620340272.760929 23
-   Link           req 205 rxreq
-   SessClose      REQ_CLOSE 0.000
-   End            

*   << BeReq    >> 32959     
-   Begin          bereq 32958 fetch
-   VCL_use        boot
-   Timestamp      Start: 1620340272.920595 0.000000 0.000000
-   BereqMethod    GET
-   BereqURL       /favicon.ico
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.0
-   BereqHeader    Host: example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Host: example.com
-   BereqHeader    X-Real-IP: 67.161.183.181
-   BereqHeader    Ssl-Offloaded: 1
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Proto: https
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-Port: 443
-   BereqHeader    Pragma: no-cache
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
-   BereqHeader    sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
-   BereqHeader    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36
-   BereqHeader    Accept: image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,image/svg+xml,image/*,*/*;q=0.8
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
-   BereqHeader    Sec-Fetch-Dest: image
-   BereqHeader    Referer: https://example.com/
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es-ES;q=0.8,es;q=0.7
-   BereqHeader    Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.1802093982.1619119977; _gid=GA1.2.56339638.1620338153; form_key=djHykwYumX1hgtiw; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; mage-messages=; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previou
-   BereqHeader    X-Forwarded-For: 67.161.183.181, 172.26.4.151
-   BereqHeader    grace: none
-   BereqHeader    Accept-Encoding: gzip
-   BereqProtocol  HTTP/1.1
-   BereqHeader    X-Varnish: 32959
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_FETCH
-   VCL_return     fetch
-   FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
-   Timestamp      Beresp: 1620340272.920635 0.000039 0.000039
-   Timestamp      Error: 1620340272.920639 0.000043 0.000004
-   BerespProtocol HTTP/1.1
-   BerespStatus   503
-   BerespReason   Service Unavailable
-   BerespReason   Backend fetch failed
-   BerespHeader   Date: Thu, 06 May 2021 22:31:12 GMT
-   BerespHeader   Server: Varnish
-   VCL_call       BACKEND_ERROR
-   BerespHeader   content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
-   BerespHeader   Retry-After: 5
-   VCL_return     deliver
-   Storage        malloc Transient
-   Length         282
-   BereqAcct      0 0 0 0 0 0
-   End
```

There are no errors showing in the nginx error.log and the nginx access.log only shows this:

```
[06/May/2021:22:52:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 503 280 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36"
```

Magento logs are also not showing anything.

Port 8080 is also open on the backend server.

The site works if I don't use varnish. Not sure what else to check or test at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the key information in the logs:

```
-   FetchError     backend default: unhealthy
```

The problem is not that the backend is technically unavailable, but the fact that the health checking probe fails. This means that the backend is administratively down.

Please run the following command to confirm this:

```
varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health
```

Because you didn't specify a `.url` option in your probe, I'm assuming the homepage will be checked. Given the *2 second timeout*, I'm also hoping that the homepage responds before the timeout kicks in.

I see that you're using Magento. It could be a good idea to use `/pub/health_check.php` as your health checking endpoint.

I also answered a similar question about `503` errors in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/324881/magento-2-4-varnish-error-503/325184#325184.

Please let me know if the `varnishlog -g raw -i Backend_health` is helpful and if you see these probing attempts in your Nginx logs. Based on that, we can further investigate. Please also read the related topic about `503` errors.

Comment: When I ran that command, this is what I got back: `0 Backend_health - default Still sick 4---X-R- 0 5 10 0.060819 0.000000 HTTP/1.1 302 Found`

Comment: Ok, I managed to get it working on my site. I originally had the .url as `.url = "/pub/health_check.php";` which would cause errors so I removed it. I changed it to `.url = "/health_check.php";` simply removing the pub, and it works. Thanks for your help.